# how can I click this webpage button using c#win form application

Tags: c#, button, webbrowser-control

I've been trying to use my windows form application webBrowser control and a button to click a button from http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input the "Check" Button, which validates my html code but the button has no id which makes webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById() not work. I have tried bytag but have not much experience with this how can I click the CHECK button on **http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input** page in my webbrowser using C#. Here is the code that is the element from the webpage.

```
<p class="submit_button">
<input title="Submit for validation" type="submit" value="Check" `enter code here`style="display: none;
<a class="submit" href="#">
<span>Check</span>
</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need some Javascript to do this. E.g. the following:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
var i = 0;
var button = null;

for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].hasAttribute('title')) {
    if (els[i].attributes['title']="Submit for validation") 
        button = els[i];
        break;
    }
}
button.click();
```

This is untested, but should do the trick.

Comment: I have tried to use your code by double pressing the button i want to use on the design and entering the cs where i tried to paste the above text into my c# winform application but i just got errors.? what am i doing wrong do i need to do something to make it work and push the button from the webpage in my webbrowser control using my button ???

Comment: You have to execute the above JAVASCRIPT against the Webbrowser control on the button click. E.g. see here: http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/

Comment: Also see this related post with some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438336/how-can-i-click-this-webpage-button-using-cwin-form-application/25438572?noredirect=1#comment39722684_25438572